# How to download a xlsx file from web in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to download an excel file from this website. but unfortunately my code unable to download the excel file. There is a download button, somehow I have click that button from python. Please check my code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
 from selenium import webdriver
 from fake_useragent import UserAgent

 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'}

 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')


 page = 'https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w16'

 driver.get(page)


 inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("fileactions.files.download")
 #inputElement.clear()
 #inputElement.send_keys(company)
 inputElement.submit()
```

Comment: I can't find any download button there, unless I have to signup?

Comment: Yes you have to signup to see that button.

Comment: what happens with inputElement.click()  ?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: is there an error? No error and does click?

Comment: No error.  first click working, here is the code                                  inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("fileactions.files.download")
inputElement.click()                                                                            but the second click is not working. No error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work ok for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

page = 'https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w16'

driver.get(page)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400)") 

dropdownElement = driver.find_element_by_id("fileactions.files.download")
dropdownElement.click()

downloadElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/div[2]/div")
downloadElement.click()
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer @chitown88

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way forward here would be to use the [Python SDK](https://github.com/datadotworld/data.world-py).

Alternatively, you could use `requests` and download the dataset with an API call. Take a look at these endpoints:

https://apidocs.data.world/toolkit/api/api-endpoints/datasets/downloaddataset
https://apidocs.data.world/toolkit/api/api-endpoints/files/downloadfile

An example of the former:

```python
url = 'https://api.data.world/v0/download/makeovermonday/2019w16'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token-from-https://data.world/integrations/python'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('dataset.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: so one question do I have to put my token here:  'Bearer my-token-from-https://data.world/integrations/python'

Answer (score 0):

> You are expecting the download to start after you click on the icon button but it only shows a pop-up panel that has the actual download button. To start the download you have to click on that button.

**First,** `submit()` only works on forms. In the given page, the download button can't be submitted. You have to use `click()`.

**Second,** After you click on the first button it shows a pop-up modal with the download link. You have to click on that button to actually start the download. You have to click the following element to start the download.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.open > ul > li > a");
```